# Validation error involving numericality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I am working with validations for the first time and I'm trying to validate an amount_spent and a no_of_purchases field so that it only takes in integers and not strings. So 200 would be valid but 'two-hundred' wouldn't be. However, when I try to do this test, the string part fails but I'm unsure as to why. Here is a snippet of my rspec test file:

```
it 'requires a # of purchases' do
  customer = Customer.new(valid_customer.merge(no_of_purchases: ''))
  customer_2 = Customer.new(valid_customer.merge(no_of_purchases: 0))
  customer_3 = Customer.new(valid_customer.merge(no_of_purchases: 'twenty'))
  expect(customer).to_not be_valid
  expect(customer.errors[:no_of_purchases]).to include "can't be blank"
  expect(customer_2).to be_valid
  expect(customer_3).to_not be_valid
  expect(customer_3.errors[:no_of_purchases]).to include "is not a number"
end

it 'requires an amount spent' do
  customer = Customer.new(valid_customer.merge(amount_spent: ''))
  customer_2 = Customer.new(valid_customer.merge(no_of_purchases: 0))
  customer_3 = Customer.new(valid_customer.merge(no_of_purchases: 'twenty'))
  expect(customer).to_not be_valid
  expect(customer.errors[:amount_spent]).to include "can't be blank"
  expect(customer_2).to be_valid
  expect(customer_3).to_not be_valid
  expect(customer_3.errors[:no_of_purchases]).to include "is not a number"
end
```

Here is my model file:

```
 validates_presence_of :first_name
 validates_presence_of :last_name
 validates_presence_of :email
 validates_presence_of :no_of_purchases, numericality: true
 validates_presence_of :amount_spent, numericality: true
```

I'm not seeing the error. I've specified numericality true so it shouldn't validate a string. The only thing that could be the problem is that I've placed a default value 0 in my schema file. I'm pretty sure that is the problem because when I use binding.pry customer 3 has a no_of_purchase, amount_spent as 0 instead of 'twenty'.

Question 1: why does it do that?
Question 2: How do I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at first glance I can see that you're using `validates_presence_of` incorrectly.  I am unsure what version of Rails you are using, but the following answer will be relevant for Rails 3 and 4.

Lets focus on these two lines:

```
validates_presence_of :no_of_purchases, numericality: true
validates_presence_of :amount_spent, numericality: true
```

The explicit `validates_something_of` validations perform one, and only one, validation check at a time.  For `validates_presence_of`, you are asking Rails to check the presence of this attribute and nothing else.  Appending `numericality: true` simply passes in a hash of options which are ignored.  This is why your numericality check is not working in your example code.

To get this to work, we can use the built in `validates` method to apply the numericality validator to both of your attributes above:

```
validates :no_or_purchases, :amount_spent, numericality: true
```

Note that I didn't add an explicit presence validation.  This is built into the numericality check by default (since nil is not a number!).

Hope this helps.  Also, the [Rails validation's documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of) explains how to do this, and many other built in validations, too.

Comment: Thanks phonk64. I was using Rails 4 so I guess what I was doing was outdated. Thanks for pointing that out. Much appreciated.